# Umlaut Characters: How do I convert “Ã<0x9c>” to “Ü” in Java?

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, special-characters

I have a string that contains "Ã<0x9c>".  It's not exactly those characters, the best way I can describe it is:

- Looks like "Ã" in Postgres DB / Datagrip Viewer.
- Looks like "Ã<0x9c>" when copied from Datagrip into Sublime Text.

I have another program that does a String match and it expects this “Ü”.
So I assume "Ã<0x9c>" is equivalent to “Ü” in some form.

My question is how do I convert "Ã<0x9c>" to “Ü” in Java for the set of these generic characters? I don't want to solve it for just this one character.

So if "Ã<0x9c>" is encoding1 and “Ü” is encoding2.  How do I convert from encoding1 to encoding2.

Also, what would encoding1 and encoding2 be called?
My googling says encoding2 are called umlaut characters but I don't know what encoding1 is called.

Comment: If DataGrip has a charset or character encoding setting—possibly a setting which is particular to that database connection—you need to set that to UTF-8.  Some databases also have their own charset property for each catalog and/or table;  I don’t know if Postgres is one of them.  One thing is certain:  *Under no circumstances* should you be doing any of this conversion in Java code.  Instead, make the database retrieval itself behave correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a conflating of the ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) and UTF-8 encodings. Let's see:

In UTF-8, the Unicode character [U+00DC](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00DC) (Ü) is encoded as 0xC3 0x9C.

In [Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), 0xC3 is the letter A with tilde (Ã), but 0xC9 doesn't have a corresponding character (glyph). That's why you see `Ã<0xC9>`.

So, the string (or byte array) you have is probably encoded in in UTF-8, and should be decoded as such.

Since you asked for how to convert, here's a demonstration:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte[] input = {(byte) 0xc3, (byte)0x9c};

    var s = new String(input, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(s);

    var out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    var writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

    writer.write(s);
    writer.flush();
    byte[] result = out.toByteArray();

    System.out.println(result.length);
    System.out.printf("%x\n", result[0]);
}
```

which prints

```
Ü
1
dc
```

Oops, forgot to mention that 0xDC is same character in Unicode and Latin-1, "Latin Capital Letter U with Diaeresis".

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] b = new byte[] {(char)'Ã', (byte)0x9c};
String capitalUUmlaut = new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF8);
```

What you are seeing is the multi byte UTF-8 encoding of Unicode. ASCII, 7 bits, is a subset. Other Unicode code points are more than one byte, every one with the highest bit 1.

Note that I use a byte array. For a corrupted String, there already could have been done some Charset conversion, which translate the bytes wrong. Even here the `Ã` might not be possible in every Charset.

Best inspect the database for the used encoding (Charset) of the DDL and specify that.